# Empty listgrid record cause

Tags: gwt, smartgwt, smartgwt-pro

My client side code is as follows where I am sending some data to the server to just print out the output. But when it returns from the server I get a empty listgrid record. what is the cause for this.

Here is the screen shot of the issue

[image]

```
if (fieldName.equals("Approve"))
{
IButton button = new IButton();
button.setHeight(18);
button.setWidth(65);
button.setTitle("Approve");
button.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler()
{
    public void onClick(ClickEvent event)
    {
        DebugTools.print("SOID " + record.getAttribute("supplierOrderID") + " SODID" + record.getAttribute("sodID")+" sordID "+record.getAttribute("sordID"));
        approveProduct(record.getAttribute("supplierOrderID"), record.getAttribute("sodID"),record.getAttribute("sordID"));
    }

private void approveProduct(String supplierOrderID, String sodID, String sordID)
{
    Record record = new Record();
                                record.setAttribute("supplierOrderID", supplierOrderID);
                                record.setAttribute("sodID", sodID);
                                record.setAttribute("sordID",sordID);
                                historyGrid.addData(record, callback);

}

          DSCallback callback = new DSCallback()
{
    @Override
    public void execute(DSResponse response, Object rawData, DSRequest request)
    {
        Record[] records = response.getData();

        if (records != null && records.length > 0)
        {
                             Record record = records[0];
                             JavaScriptObject js = record.getJsObj();                            JSONObject json = new JSONObject(js);                          System.out.println("  records.length    " + records.length);                    for (int i = 0; i < records.length; i++)    {                       Record recordd = records[i];
                                            JavaScriptObject jss = recordd.getJsObj();
                                            JSONObject jsonn = new JSONObject(jss);
                                            System.out.println(jsonn.toString());
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            };
```

and on the server side my add method is very simple for now where I am just printing the data I received from the client

```
public DSResponse add(DSRequest dsRequest) throws Exception
{
    DSResponse dsResponse = new DSResponse();
    Long user_idlong = SessionUtills.getSessionUser(dsRequest.getHttpServletRequest());

    System.out.println("sodID       " + dsRequest.getFieldValue("sodID").toString());
    System.out.println("PRODUCT APPROVED !!!!!!!!!!!!!" + " SUPPLIER ORDER ID " + dsRequest.getFieldValue("supplierOrderID").toString());
    return dsResponse;

}
```

I have also attached the shot of the issue

Comment: Is there any exception logged in development mode?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is at server side from where you are sending an empty `DSResponse` back to client hence at client side you are getting zero length records array.

Return a valid `DSResponse` that contains all the information of the newly added record.

---

Please have a look at

- [DSResponse#setData()](http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwtee/server/javadoc/com/isomorphic/datasource/DSResponse.html#setData%28java.lang.Object%29)
- [DSResponse#setStatus()](http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwtee/server/javadoc/com/isomorphic/datasource/DSResponse.html#setStatus%28int%29)

Must read [The basic flow of logic for handling DataSource requests](http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/javadoc/com/smartgwt/client/docs/ServerDataIntegration.html)

Comment: thanks for your comments.it was helpful.. Now taking my code as it is and just want to avoid that empty record,what I need to do. I will appreciate your help.

Comment: Why not? Please can you tell me how are your calling `add()` method from client side.

Comment: Is data added in database? Are you using `ds.xml` file?

Comment: cheers!!...I have this button which when clicked will fire this method approveProduct(..). In this method I have this addData method which sends the request to the server..historyGrid.addData(record, callback);

Comment: regarding your second comment. yes I am adding the data to the db.but for now I just want to print in the console that the data has been updated but without that issue arising which i have shown in the screenshot

Comment: Braj still waiting for your help